# Python Pandas Update / Replace

Tags: python, pandas

struggling to get to grips with update/merge/concat etc to achieve what I thought was a simple merge or update procedure. I have df (recorded values) and df2 (times series with 0s), and would like to update/replace the values in df2 with the corresponding recorded values of df, matching on date_time.

Example: df=

```
Date_Time   Perc
03/03/2010 00:05    1.0
03/03/2010 00:15    2.0
```

df2 =

```
  Date_Time Perc
03/03/2010 00:00    0.0
03/03/2010 00:05    0.0
03/03/2010 00:10    0.0
03/03/2010 00:15    0.0
03/03/2010 00:20    0.0
```

Where the result would return:

```
Date_Time   Perc
03/03/2010 00:00    0.0
03/03/2010 00:05    1.0
03/03/2010 00:10    0.0
03/03/2010 00:15    2.0
03/03/2010 00:20    0.0
```

I'm finding this frustrating as there is good info and examples on http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html and a great SO question with multiple solutions on [How to update values in a specific row in a Python Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036911/how-to-update-values-in-a-specific-row-in-a-python-pandas-dataframe) but having tried several approaches, none work.

Tried so far: Re-indexing to Date_time and df2.update(df) with variations, multiple merging/join/concat variations, an adapted definition (below) with apply...and now wondering if I need to use iterrows (see below?). 
Any suggestions on pointers in the right direction would be appreciated...maybe I'm missing something fundamental in my approach...

```
def update_vals(row, data=data):
    if row.Date_Time == df.Date_Time:
        row.Perc = df.Perc
    return row

for index, row in df2['Date_Time'].iterrows():
    x = df2['Date_Time']
    for index, row in df['Date_Time'].iterrows():
        x2 = df['Date_Time']
        if x2 ==x:
            df2['Perc'] = df['Perc']
```

Thought this would work as well, but it results in (ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis)

```
df.set_index('Date_Time', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('Date_Time', inplace=True)
df2.update(df[['Perc']])
```

Comment: `df2.update(df)` works for me.

Comment: @hellpanderrr that's strange, when I run it my output looses the full df2 (see below 00:00 time stamp is gone) I'm tying to preserve the complete df2, and only change the matching times values of 'perc' : Date_Time Perc
0  03/03/2010 00:05  1.0
1  03/03/2010 00:15  2.0
2  03/03/2010 00:10  0.0
3  03/03/2010 00:15  0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df2`

```
                  Perc
Date_Time   
03/03/2010 00:00    0
03/03/2010 00:05    0
03/03/2010 00:10    0
03/03/2010 00:15    0
03/03/2010 00:20    0
```

`df`

```
                 Perc
Date_Time   
03/03/2010 00:05    1
03/03/2010 00:15    2
```

`df2.update(df)`

```
                 Perc
Date_Time   
03/03/2010 00:00    0
03/03/2010 00:05    1
03/03/2010 00:10    0
03/03/2010 00:15    2
03/03/2010 00:20    0
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help...have to admit, found you were right, and that in my actual data set that is over 500k lines, there is  a duplicate Date_time, that threw out the update process...but, learnt more, and maybe this will help someone else...many thanks..