# How to swap columns conditionally in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe  `df` with 4 columns. For example here is a toy example:

```
foo1    foo2     foo3  foo4
egg     cheese   2     1
apple   pear     1     3
french  spanish  10    1
```

The columns are foo1, foo2, foo3 and foo4

I would like to swap columns foo1 and foo2 and also swap columns foo3 and foo4 when foo3 < foo4.  So the result would be:

```
foo1     foo2    foo3  foo4
cheese   egg     1     2
apple    pear    1     3
spanish  french  1     10
```

I can find the rows that need swapping with `df[df['foo3'] < df['foo4']]`  but how can I do the swapping efficiently. My dataframe is large.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036911/how-to-update-values-in-a-specific-row-in-a-python-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pandas.Series.where` function to construct new data frame based on the condition:

```
pairs = [('foo1', 'foo2'), ('foo3', 'foo4')]  # construct pairs of columns that need to swapped

df_out = pd.DataFrame() 

# for each pair, swap the values if foo3 < foo4
for l, r in pairs:
    df_out[l] = df[l].where(df.foo3 < df.foo4, df[r])
    df_out[r] = df[r].where(df.foo3 < df.foo4, df[l])

df_out
#     foo1   foo2   foo3  foo4
#0  cheese    egg      1     2
#1   apple   pear      1     3
#2 spanish french      1    10
```

Answer (score 7):

You can find the rows with `df[df['foo3'] < df['foo4']]`, yes, but if you use the Boolean series instead, you can easily accomplish your goal:

```
s = df['foo3'] < df['foo4']
df.loc[s, ['foo1','foo2']] = df.loc[s, ['foo2','foo1']].values
df.loc[s, ['foo3','foo4']] = df.loc[s, ['foo4','foo3']].values
```

Note, you need the `.values` at the end of the RHS to prevent Pandas from aligning on column names, which will undermine the purpose.

Comment: Can I swap foo3 and foo4 at the same time?

Comment: That's possible, yes. Go python simultaneous assignment!!! Why don't you try it and let me know if you hit a bump..?

Comment: I needed to de-Series-ify the row index `s` for this method, for example `s=list(df['foo3'] < df['foo4']`, otherwise I get "unalignable index" error