# Fill empty Dataframe with filled Dataframe and different column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
Columns: [TERMID, NAME, TYP, NAMECHANGE, ALIASES, SUCHREGELN, ZUW, SEOTEXT1, SEOTEXT2, SEOKommentar, DBIKommentar]
```

This is my empty dataframe.

```
      one  two  three  four
0  1.0  4.0    2.4   6.4
1  2.0  3.0    4.4   4.1
2  3.0  2.0    7.0   1.0
3  4.0  1.0    9.0   5.0
```

I need to fill these values into my empty dataframe.

So lets say`'TERMID'` takes the value from `'one'`, `'TYP'` the value of `'two'`, `'ZUW'` the value from `'three'` and last but not least `'SEOKommentar'` takes the value from `'four'`

The empty dataframe needs to get filled row by row, and the ones which are not filled should say NaN.

How can I do this in an accurate way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update values in a specific row in a Python Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036911/how-to-update-values-in-a-specific-row-in-a-python-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: No not yet to be honest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the second dataframe and then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the columns to the original empty dataframe columns:

Creating the empty data frame:

```
s = 'TERMID,NAME,TYP,NAMECHANGE,ALIASES,SUCHREGELN,ZUW,SEOTEXT1,SEOTEXT2,SEOKommentar,DBIKommentar'
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=s.split(','))
```

---

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [TERMID, NAME, TYP, NAMECHANGE, ALIASES, SUCHREGELN, ZUW, SEOTEXT1, SEOTEXT2, SEOKommentar, DBIKommentar]
Index: []
```

---

Solution (`df1` is the second dataframe in your example):

```
d = {'one': 'TERMID', 'two': 'TYP', 'three': 'ZUW', 'four': 'SEOKommentar'}
df = df1.rename(columns=d).reindex(columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
   TERMID  NAME  TYP  NAMECHANGE  ALIASES  SUCHREGELN  ZUW  SEOTEXT1  \
0     1.0   NaN  4.0         NaN      NaN         NaN  2.4       NaN   
1     2.0   NaN  3.0         NaN      NaN         NaN  4.4       NaN   
2     3.0   NaN  2.0         NaN      NaN         NaN  7.0       NaN   
3     4.0   NaN  1.0         NaN      NaN         NaN  9.0       NaN   

   SEOTEXT2  SEOKommentar  DBIKommentar  
0       NaN           6.4           NaN  
1       NaN           4.1           NaN  
2       NaN           1.0           NaN  
3       NaN           5.0           NaN
```

Comment: This raises a ValueError in my code. Saying I cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: @yannickhau do you have duplicate column names? works fine for the example you have provided in the question

Comment: yeah there is one named the same.. should I rename this one first probably?

Comment: @yannickhau if possible yes, you shouldnt be having 2 same column names ideally