# Replace two rows in a Pandas DataFrame with five rows?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I know how to append rows, delete rows, concatenate data frames, but how do you do cut and insert rows in a dataframe **without having to delete, splice, and concatenate**? Is there a built-in method for this? Let's say I have a DataFrame:

```
Index A B
0 1 2
1 2 2
2 3 3
3 4 5
4 5 5
```

and I want to replace rows 1 & 2 with:

```
0 5 5
1 5 5
2 5 5
```

so I get:

```
Index A B
0 1 2
1 5 5
2 5 5
3 5 5
4 4 5
5 5 5
```

Comment: does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723830/replace-rows-in-a-pandas-data-frame

Comment: @depperm yes it does, thank you!