# Replace rows in Dataframe using index from another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with identical structures `df` and `df_a`. `df_a` is a subset of `df` that I need to reintegrate into `df`. Essentially, `df_a` has various rows (with varying indices) from `df` that have been manipulated.

Below is an example of indices of each `df` and `df_a`. These both have the same column structure so all the columns are the same, it's only the rows and idex of the rows that differ.

```
>> df
index  ..  other_columns  ..
0   
1
2
3
. .
9999
10000
10001

[10001 rows x 20 columns]

>> df_a
index  ..  other_columns  ..
5
12
105
712
. .
9824
9901
9997

[782 rows x 20 columns]
```

So, I want to overwrite only the rows in `df` that have the indices of `df_a` with the corresponding rows in `df_a`. I checked out [Replace rows in a Pandas df with rows from another df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267372/replace-rows-in-a-pandas-df-with-rows-from-another-df) and [replace rows in a pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723830/replace-rows-in-a-pandas-data-frame) but neither of those tell how to use the indices of another dataframe to replace the values in the rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```py
df.loc[df_a.index, :] = df_a[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this wants you meant, for that you would need to be more specific, but if the first data frame was modified to be a new data frame with different indexes, then you can use this code to reset back the indexes:

```
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[5,4,2,7]}, index=[2,55,62,74])
df_a.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
print(df_a)

PRINTS:
   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  4
2  3  2
3  4  7
```